# A program that let's the user choose a shape from five, but it draws all the same shapes at once, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
from turtle import*
def square():
  for i in range(4):
    forward(30)
    right(90)

def triangle():
  for i in range(3):
    forward(50)
    left(120)

def pentagon():
  for i in range(5):
    forward(30)
    right(72)

def hexagon():
  for i in range(6):
    forward(30)
    right(60)

def star():
  for i in range(5):
    forward(50)
    right(144)

def pause():
  penup()
  forward(70)
  pendown()

shape = (input("Type one of these shapes square, triangle, pentagon, hexagon, star"))



if shape == square():
    print (square())

elif shape == triangle():
    print (triangle())


elif shape == pentagon():
    print (pentagon())

elif shape == hexagon():
    print (hexagon())

elif shape == star():
    print (star())
else:
  print("Shape is not valid, please input a valid one!")
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
if shape == square():
```

it calls the `square` function, which draws the square. Then it compares the user's input to the return value. Since the function doesn't return anything, the comparison fails.

You do this for all the shapes, so it ends up drawing all the shapes.

You should be comparing the user's input to a string, not calling the functions.

```
if shape == "square":
```

You also should not use `print()` around the calls to the shape functions, since they don't return anything that should be printed. So it should be like this:

```
if shape == "square":
    square()
elif shape == "triangle":
    triangle()
...
else:
    print("shape is not valid, please input a valid one!")
```

Instead of all the `if` statements, a more clever way would be to use a dictionary that maps from shape names to functions:

```
shape_map = {"square": square, "triangle": triangle, "pentagon": pentagon, ...}
if shape in shape_map:
    shape_map[shape]()
else:
    print("shape is not valid, please input a valid one!")
```